# Equivalent Queries, different results and execution time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

EDIT: Query Plans Linked to:

[Bad Query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jkz1ocu4745hodz/BadQuery.sqlplan?dl=0)

[Good Query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/id06c31k25z3s0f/GoodQueryPlan.sqlplan?dl=0)

So I am working on an MSSQL system and I am rewriting some queries.  I decided to play with my predicates mostly by moving them from the WHERE clause, and stuffing them into my JOIN clauses.  When I did that, it returned twice as many rows, and the execution time went from seconds to minutes.

I'd like to know what happened because I thought that the Query Analyzer more often than not would stuff the predicates into the JOIN clause since those rows would be discarded eventually.

Any help on why these queries wouldn't be equivalent would be greatly appreciated, I'm just not DB Strong Enough to know where to look..

**Good Query:**

```
FROM [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_C005] c005 
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_FI] fi ON c005.ID_FI = fi.ID
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_CPPE] kp ON c005.ID_PE = kp.ID_PE AND  fi.id = kp.id_fi
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] vko ON c005.F7010 = vko.code 
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_VF] vf on vf.id_fi = fi.id and vf.VerkOrg = vko.code
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] land ON fi.land = land.code 
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] title ON kp.Titel = title.code and title.loskz = 0 and title.KatSperre = 0 and title.sprachenr = 0 and title.katnr = 23
WHERE kp.loskz = 0
and vko.loskz = 0
and vko.KatSperre = 0
and vko.sprachenr = 0
and vko.katnr = 274
and vko.ExtKey = '0014'
and land.loskz = 0
and land.KatSperre = 0
and land.sprachenr = 1000
and land.katnr = 2
and fi.loskz = 0
and fi.F7029 = 0
and vf.loskz = 0
and vf.F7023 = 0
and vf.F7152 = 0
and c005.del = 0
and kp.f7017 = 0
```

**Bad Query:**

```
FROM [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_C005] c005 
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_FI] fi ON c005.ID_FI = fi.ID AND fi.loskz = 0 AND fi.F7029 = 0
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_CPPE] kp ON c005.ID_PE = kp.ID_PE AND fi.id = kp.id_fi AND kp.loskz = 0 AND kp.f7017 = 0
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] vko ON c005.F7010 = vko.code AND vko.loskz = 0 AND vko.KatSperre = 0 AND vko.sprachenr = 0 AND vko.katnr = 274 and vko.ExtKey = '0014'
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_VF] vf on vf.id_fi = fi.id and vf.VerkOrg = vko.code AND vf.loskz = 0 AND vf.F7023 = 0 AND vf.F7152 = 0
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] land ON fi.land = land.code AND land.loskz = 0 AND land.KatSperre = 0 AND land.sprachenr = 1000 AND land.katnr = 2
LEFT JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] title ON kp.Titel = title.code and title.loskz = 0 and title.KatSperre = 0 and title.sprachenr = 0 and title.katnr = 23
WHERE c005.del = 0
```

Comment: Please provide execution plans

Comment: The queries are not the same because in case of left outer join the criteria will only limit the rows fetched from the outer joined table, and still bring the rows from CRM_C005 but in the original query it will leave out the rows completely -- so having anything related to outer joins in the where clause turns it into a inner join.

Comment: @dfundako Does SO have a preferred upload spot?

Comment: @dfundako Done, the plans have been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose this example: I have a table of 100,000 phone calls.  There are certain types of phone calls: inbound and outbound.  When I write a query that is

```
SELECT * 
FROM calls c
LEFT JOIN calltypes ct
ON c.calltypeID = ct.calltypeID
WHERE c.calltypeID = 1 --Assume this is inbound
```

This query will return ONLY the inbound calls from my calls table.

Now, if I write:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM calls c
    LEFT JOIN calltypes ct
    ON c.calltypeID = ct.calltypeID
    AND c.calltypeID = 1
```

I will return 100,000 rows. The left join cannot find a suitable join condition, so it returns a null value for the values of the ct table. This is an example of why your query probably returns so many more rows when you use your where clauses in the join conditions instead.

Comment: My goodness, how have I gotten this far without knowing the difference!  I've always put my "c.calltypeID" in the WHERE clause so I guess I have never had to learn.  But I can see how these extra rows will carry through the sequence bloating my result set.

Comment: Yes you are converting your left joins to inner joins in your original query.. It is not the equivalent query to the one you wrote. If you have been doing this all along, then likely you have many queries returning incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

By referencing the outer side of the join in the where you turned it into a regular join
You might as well do this

```
FROM [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_C005] c005 
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_FI] fi 
       ON fi.ID    = c005.ID_FI 
      and            c005.del = 0
      and fi.loskz = 0
      and fi.F7029 = 0
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_CPPE] kp 
       ON kp.ID_PE = c005.ID_PE  
      AND kp.id_fi = c005.ID_FI 
      and kp.loskz = 0 
      and kp.f7017 = 0
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] vko 
       ON vko.code      = c005.F7010     
      and vko.loskz     = 0
      and vko.KatSperre = 0
      and vko.sprachenr = 0
      and vko.katnr     = 274
      and vko.ExtKey    = '0014'
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_VF] vf 
       on vf.id_fi   = c005.ID_FI 
      and vf.VerkOrg = vko.code 
      and vf.loskz   = 0
      and vf.F7023   = 0
      and vf.F7152   = 0
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] land 
       ON land.code      = fi.land  
      and land.loskz     = 0
      and land.KatSperre = 0
      and land.sprachenr = 1000
      and land.katnr     = 2
JOIN [CONNECT_PROD].[dbo].[CRM_KA] title 
       ON title.code      = kp.Titel 
      and title.loskz     = 0 
      and title.KatSperre = 0 
      and title.sprachenr = 0 
      and title.katnr     = 23
```