# What's the difference between these joins?

Tags: t-sql

What's the difference between

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TOOL T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PREVENT_USE P ON T.ID = P.TOOL_ID
WHERE
    P.ID IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TOOL T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PREVENT_USE P ON T.ID = P.TOOL_ID AND P.ID IS NULL
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent Queries, different results and execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485189/equivalent-queries-different-results-and-execution-time)

Comment: The WHERE will exclude records from your dataset, LEFT JOIN returns NULL when it can't match condition.

Comment: @dfundako I think the first query is a Left Anti Join whereas the second query attempts to do this but fails.  They are not equivalent

Comment: Of course they aren't equivalent. Read the link I posted. It explains why they are not the same and why they return different results.

Comment: @dfundako fair enough, that is a rather misleading title. ;-)

Comment: @dfundako, it really seams a duplicate question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom query is equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TOOL T
```

since it is not limiting the result set but rather producing a joined table with a lot of null fields for the right part of the join.

The first query is a left anti join.

Comment: Thanks, @alexander-toptygin!
In addition, I would like to register here a post that found today and complements your answer: https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/logical-query-processing-part-6-where-clause